# Ignore the other string from input if certain string from array is detected

Tags: c++

I need to create a program that print out the input value if on the first line of the input exists in an array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    std::string avai_commands[] = {"PRINTAGE","CREATE"}; // Both must have the same functionality

    std::string insert;
    while(std::getline(std::cin,insert) && insert != "quit") {
        if(std::find(std::begin(avai_commands), std::end(avai_commands),insert) != std::end(avai_commands)) {
            std::cout << "New item created: " << insert << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Invalid Command";
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So in this case on the input I wrote: `CREATE main_text` now that the console throws "Invalid Command" (which what I was expected to happens). But my main goal is I want to make it so that the `main_text` to be print if the `CREATE` or  `PRINTAGE` is detected on the first line of the input.

For instance, lets say I wrote this on the console: `CREATE Hello` then the input 'Hello' should be print.

Comment: `CREATE main_text` is on a single line? In the text you write that `CREATE` is the first line, but `getline` reads the whole line, and `insert` is `CREATE main_text`

Comment: What is the input you're expecting? If you don't want `CREATE main_text` on a single line, like @463035818_is_not_a_number said above, then `getline` doesn't make sense here, because you're overwriting `insert` with the most recent line every time. Also, is insert expected to be one string? I don't think your program does what you think it does. Step through it line by line and see if it matches what you expect.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The OP didn't express his problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse your input. For example, you can split every line you enter and verify if it starts with the commands you want:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string avai_commands[] = {"PRINTAGE","CREATE"}; // Both must have the same functionality

    std::string insert;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, insert) && insert != "quit") {
        if (insert == "")
            continue;
        
        std::string command, item;
        std::vector<std::string> items;
        std::stringstream ss(insert);
        
        if (!std::getline(ss, command, ' ')) {
            std::cout << "Wrong input" << '\n';
            break;
        }
        
        while (std::getline(ss, item, ' ')) {
            items.push_back(item);
        }
        
        if (items.size() == 0) {
            std::cout << "Usage: PRINTAGE|CREATE <argument>" << '\n';
            break;
        }
        
        if(std::find(std::begin(avai_commands), std::end(avai_commands), command) == std::end(avai_commands)) {
            std::cout << "Invalid Command" << '\n';
            break;
        }
        
        std::cout << "New item created: ";
        for (auto& item : items)
            std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
}
```